Buscar videos en foler(ID)&subfolder Google Drive y exportar lista con nombre/ubucacion /duración del video a un spreedsheet en google colab/python
despues de intentar de varias formas, para encontrar todos los videos dentro de una carpeta y subcarpetas (lo que me falta es ahora obtener la duración de cada uno), me funcionó en google colab python el siguiente código:
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

from google.colab import auth as google_auth
google_auth.authenticate_user()

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Google API client:
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Initialize the Google Drive API client
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def search_file():
  """Search file in drive location

  Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
  TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
  for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
  """
  creds, _ = google.auth.default()
  folder_id = '1234567'
  query = f"mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.video' and '{folder_id}' in parents"

  try:
    # create drive api client
    service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
    files = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
      # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
    
      response = (
service.files().list(
              q= query,
              spaces="drive",
              fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
              pageToken=page_token,
          )
          .execute()
      )
      for file in response.get("files", []):
        # Process change
        print(f'Found file: {file.get("name")}, {file.get("id")}')
      files.extend(response.get("files", []))
      page_token = response.get("nextPageToken", None)
      if page_token is None:
        break

  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
    files = None

  return files


if __name__ == "__main__":
  search_file()

Como resultado me imprime la lista de videos en la carpeta del id propircionado folder_id = '1234567' y quiero saber como agregar el codigo para que de esos videos que encuentra agregue una columna con la duración en HH:MM:SS y expoertarlas a un spreedsheet, o al menos que me imprima en linea de comandos con la columna de duración.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda
He probado codigos que he encontrado en stackoverflow y me ayudaron a llegar hasta donde voy, pero no he logrado encontrar la forma de agregar ese metadato.
